# Which is the best way to load header, nav and footer? I used php but I'm not sure

Tags: php, html, header

I have got header.html, nav.html and footer.html. I need to load them on a index.php.
is it right? Because this works but I don't know if this is the best way to do.

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
  <header><?php require('../layout/header.html')?></header>
  <nav><?php require('../layout/nav.html')?></nav>
  <div id="content">Hello World</div>
  <footer><?php require('../layout/footer.html')?></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="../images/header.png">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your html is invalid/not needed for the header file; you don't need to repeat markup, just include the img src.

Comment: That is an example, if I had a header more complicated with a lot of rows and I don't want for every page of my website use copy and past. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple `<html>` tags in the resulting HTML, i.e., the following code is not valid:

```
<html>
 <html>
   <header></header>
 </html>
</html>
```

When you split your HTML into different files in order to reuse code, you have to consider that they will be, probably, injected in a pre-existent HTML code. Therefore, I would suggest the following code:

main.html

```
<html>
<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <?php require('../layout/header.html')?>

  <!-- Nav -->
  <?php require('../layout/nav.html')?>

  <!-- Content -->
  <div id="content">Hello World</div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <?php require('../layout/footer.html')?>
</body>
</html>
```

layout/header.html

```
<header>
   <!-- Your header HTML -->
</header>
```

layout/nav.html

```
<nav>
   <!-- Your Nav HTML -->
</nav>
```

layout/footer.hml

```
<footer>
   <!-- Your footer HTML -->
</footer>
```